# Show whether the subset $ A =\{\frac{1}{p} :p\in\mathbb{N} \text{ is prime}\}$ is open, closed , both or neither

Tags: general-topology

I must show whether the set $ A = \left\{ \frac 1 p :p\in\mathbb{N}\text{ is prime}\right\}$ is $d_A$-open, $d_A$-closed, both or neither.

**My attempt**

> If we take the subset as a sequence $\left(a_n\right)= \left\{\frac{1}{p} :p\in\mathbb{N} \text{ is prime}\right\}$, we find its limit is $0$ as $p\to\infty$.  However, this limit is not in $A$ and hence it is not closed because we have found a sequence in $A$ with its limit outside of $A$.
>
> I also think the sunset $A$ is open because it can be represented as a union of known open sets: $$\left(-\infty, \frac{1}{p_n}\right)\bigcup \left(\frac{1}{p_n},\frac{1}{p_{n-1}}\right)\bigcup \left(\frac{1}{p_{n-1}},\frac{1}{p_{n-2}}\right)\bigcup \dotsb \bigcup \left(\frac{1}{p_2},\frac{1}{p_1}\right)\bigcup \left(\frac{1}{p_1},\infty\right),$$ where $a_n$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ term of sequence $\left(a_n\right)$.

I think the intervals with $-\infty$ and $\infty$ are both open and closed, so I can use them?

Is my answer correct?  If not, I would greatly appreciate it if someone would point me in the right direction because I'm unsure about this topic.

Comment: Not closed: Correct. Open: No! Are you sure that $A$ is the union of those intervals?

Comment: Yeah that was a silly error of me, gonna have to rethink my approach.

Comment: $\{\text{curly braces}\}$ should not be excluded from the MathJax code. I edited accordingly. $$ \{a,b,c\}$$ $$ \left\{ \frac 1 a, \frac 1 b, \frac 1 c \right\}$$

Comment: (1). What is $d_A$?... (2). Open or closed in which space?

Comment: The metric space is $(\mathbb{R} , d)$ where d is Euclidean metric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that it it not closed.

Rather than writing $A$ as union of open subsets, I think you wrote $A^c$ instead.
$$A^c= (-\infty, \frac{1}{p_n})\cup (\frac{1}{p_n},\frac{1}{p_{n-1}})\cup (\frac{1}{p_{n-1}},\frac{1}{p_{n-2}})\cup \cdots \cup (\frac{1}{p_2},\frac{1}{p_1})\cup (\frac{1}{p_1},\infty).$$

I think your conclusion is $A^c$ is open and hence $A$ is closed, which is something that you have proven earlier.

Do you think $A^c$ is closed? is $\frac12$ a limit point of $A^c$? does $A^c$ contain $\frac12$? can you conclude anything about openness of $A$ if A is not closed?

Comment: Oh damn you're right that is the compliment.  If my union of intervals showed $A$ is closed, when I've already shown it isn't, then presumably that is wrong.  I think $\frac{1}{2}$ is a limit point of $A^c$ because there must some sequence that has $1/2$ as a limit with only terms belonging to $A^c$ but I can't think of any.  $A^c$ doesn't contain $\frac{1}{2}$.  If it is a limit point then $A^c$ isn't closed and A is open.

Comment: Maybe the sequence {$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}$ is not prime}?

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}$ is indeed a limit point of $A^c$, since $(1/2,\infty)\subset A^c$, but that doesn't imply that $A$ is open!

Comment: Whoops $A^c$ not being closed means $A$ is not open!  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @MikeA : "compliment" (with an "i") and "complement" (with an "e") are two different words. If I say your question is brilliant, that's a compliment (with an "i"). The complement (with an "e") of a set is another matter.

Comment: Ha thanks for pointing that out.